# Red-Gate Sql Compare SDK Alternative? -- Their auto-mapping "feature" is destroying my data

Tags: c#, sql-server, redgate

Does anybody have a good M$ Sql Server Schema Compare Tool that I can embed in my updater?  Using Red-Gate, if you remove a field and add another with the same data type, it copies the old data into the new column, screwing up my data.  There is no way to turn if off. They claim this is a "Feature"

Comment: Visual Stuido has a native one > other languages > sql server
one project for each, then you can do a compare in the menu

Comment: Perhaps you could add the new field before removing the old field, so that it doesn't copy the data over.

Comment: I have 1000's of databases deployed across 1000's of locations.  I need to be able to embed the comparison tool to our homegrown updater written in C#

Comment: That doesn't sound ideal. Have you tried altering the data type of the new column in a subtle way that doesn't matter, but may trick the auto-mapping feature into thinking it's a different column?